# Override sync method in backbone

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

I'm doing a model named person and i use parse.com javascript api. To send model to parse.com ì've created a my function send but i think it is wrong. I think that i have to override sync method with api parse.com and after use save method on the model created. It's right?

```
var Person = Backbone.Model.extend({
        defaults: {},

        initialize:function() {
            console.log("inperson");
        },

        validate:function() {
            console.log("validate");
        },

        send:function() {
            var user = new Parse.User();
            user.set("username", this.get("username"));
            user.set("password", this.get("password"));
            user.set("email", this.get("email"));

            user.signUp(null, {
                success: function(user) {

                },
                error: function(user, error) {
                    alert("Error: " + error.code + " " + error.message);
                }
            });
        }
    });

return Person;

});
```

Comment: if you're trying to use parse to create an object, you'll need to extend the `Parse.Object` not `Backbone.Model`. that said, i'm not sure i follow what you're doing. why aren't you storing a reference to the user once you invoke 'send'? why not extend `Parse.User`?

Answer (score 0):

Backbone only uses one sync method (`Backbone.sync`). All methods collections and models that are "talking" with the server goes through this one.
You can simply overwrite it by saying:

```
Backbone.sync = function(method, model, options) {
    // method is send through methodMap witch is an object:
    //var methodMap = {
    //    'create': 'POST',
    //    'update': 'PUT',
    //    'patch':  'PATCH',
    //    'delete': 'DELETE',
    //    'read':   'GET'
    //};

    // model refers to the active model and you can use model.attributes to get all the attributes. 

    // So in here you can write your integration with parse.com and not change anything else while using backbone.
    // Remember to trigger `sync` etc.        
};
```

---

But I can see that parse.com allready have a REST-api so maybe this is not the solution.

Comment: If i have two different api to send data to the server based on two different model?Example:model:person have an api becasue is supported by parse as a user (with password,mail,ecc.),and other model have different same api.I have to write an if to differetiate the case?

Comment: Yes parse have rest api but i want to use javascript api of parse